# Report training loss for a specific sample in train dataset, not the average one in the training process (TensorFlow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, epoch

I'm training an LSTM model using TensorFlow. We know that in the process of training, the is a report for `loss` and `val_loss` for every epoch which are the average of losses for train and test datasets. I'm intended to follow the loss of a specific sample in the train dataset (specific date). Also, it should be noted that I'm shuffling train data in `fit` function.

Comment: You can create a specific op for calculating loss for that sample and call that op whenever you want the loss value or put it in the summary. In the case of pure TensorFlow it will be done in session run and in case of a fit function (keras way), you would have to write custom callback.

Comment: @talos1904 Could you please add this as an answer and provide more information?

Comment: code added below

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for tracking loss for a single sample:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 
import keras 

x = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.ndarray(shape=(10, 10), dtype=np.float32)) # your sample input 
y =np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(10, )) # your sample label
y_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, 10)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=x, logits=y_labels)) # loss operation for that particular sample 
tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss) #logging loss op in summary 

print('loss op', loss)
merge = tf.summary.merge_all()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess: 
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    loss_val, merge_val = sess.run([loss, merge]) # no need to pass any feed_dict, loss value calculated is specific to that sample 
    print('loss val', loss_val)
    # merge val could be put in to tf summary writer
```

Comment: It returns this error: `module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.nn' has no attribute 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2'`

Comment: It's just the TensorFlow version issue. I am using 1.13.2 version for running the above code.